# Insert multiple rows, most of them constant

Tags: mysql, insert

I have to insert big amount of records in a table. It is not quite normalized, so most of the fields are repeated.

I know the proper command is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (field1, field2, ..., field_n) 
VALUES (value1, value2, ..., value_n),
    ...
    (value1, value2, ..., value_n)
```

But I wonder whether it is possible to keep some of the values fixed and just indicate the different ones.

Let's say instead of

```
INSERT INTO table_name (shop, month, sale)
VALUES (1, 2, 23),
    (1, 2, 28),
    (1, 2, 29),
    (1, 2, 30)
```

Having something like

```
INSERT INTO table_name (shop, month, sale)
VALUES (1, 2, 23), ... 28 / 29 / 30
```

If it is not possible I would create a procedure with a loop, feeding a string, etc. It would not be a big issue, but my point is to know if INSERT INTO has any particularity that allows doing this without procedures.

Comment: No you cant do like that...........

Comment: Yes, I saw it! Anyway, ideas that come over were useful enough to my proposal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (shop, month, sale)
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 1 as shop, 2 as month) as sm,
(SELECT 23 as sale UNION ALL SELECT 28 UNION ALL SELECT 30) as sales;
```

Comment: I like the idea, @newtover. It saves a lot of time and constants can be easily changed in case it is needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default constraint which will add the default value when you do not specify that in the insert into statement. If you specify a value that value will be added.

Just set the default value for your column in your table

```
ALTER TABLE tblname ALTER columnName SET DEFAULT 'value'
```

Refer http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp

Comment: Thank you, @Meherzad. It is a good attempt in case values are completely constant. In my case they are quite a lot, but sometimes have to change. Let's say they are like a block: 100 records with same 5 rows, 100 records with same 4 rows and one field changing, etc. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary table to insert the different values and then use insert ... select. I don't know if it will be a big saving for you:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sale_temp (sale int);
INSERT sale_temp (sale) VALUES (23), (28), (29), (30);
INSERT INTO table_name (shop, month, sale)
SELECT 1, 2, sale
  FROM sale_temp;
DROP TABLE sale_temp;
```

Comment: Thank you, @rsanchez, it is quite a saving. It is quite useful, although the answer newtover gave does not include temporary table which is something I appreciate.